# Elasticsearch - simulate foreign key behavior

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having problem modeling my documents in Elasticsearch, while a foreign key in a relational db would have solved my problem very easily.
The closer I got was trying a parent child relationship, but my case has multiple parents to the same document ( I might looked at it the wrong way)

Consider the following 3 documents from type person:
doc1:

```
{
  _id: 10
  "source":{
    "first_name": "child1_first_name",
    "last_name": "child1_last_name",
    "age" : 10,
    "phone": "0505055050",
    .
    .
    "mother":{
      "id": 100
      "firt_name": "mother1",
      "last_name": "last_name1"
    }
  }
}
```

doc2:

```
{
  _id: 11
  "source":{
    "first_name": "child2_first_name",
    "last_name": "child2_last_name",
    "age" : 12,
    "phone": "878787878",
    .
    .
    "mother":{
      "id": 100
      "firt_name": "mother1",
      "last_name": "last_name1"
    }
  }
}
```

doc3:

```
{
  _id: 100
  "source":{
    "first_name": "mother1",
    "last_name": "last_name1",
    "age" : 40,
    "phone": "12212121212",
    .
    .
    "mother":{}
  }
}
```

My problem is when the mother update her last name or first name.
Do I need to find all documents, that id 100 is their mother, and change their inner documents to the right first name and last name?

This is just an example, my case is that I need to update 100+ children with the correct and new name of their mother.
In a relational database this would be easy by using foreign key.

I tried to use this [reference](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you look for this:
Parent and Child documents in Elasticsearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

So you would first need to adapt the `mapping`so that `mother` can be used as parent and as a type itself -> more on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html

Then index as described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html .

```
PUT /index_name/child/10?parent=100
```

A change to the parent document now should lead to a change in all child documents.

Side new: This plugin might be interesting for the solution: http://siren.solutions/relational-joins-for-elasticsearch-the-siren-join-plugin/

Comment: Thanks! but what if a person has a mother and father? it means he has 2 parents, what should I do in this case?

Comment: it looks like that ES is the wrong tool then. If you want a relational DBS you should also use one.

Comment: You can only have a `one-to-many` relationship in ES. The other option is to repeat the data but then changing the parent you will have to update all child documents.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not the tool just by having this problem. Elasticsearch give me a lot of functionality a relational db doesn't give me, like make sure my entity fields are searchable. I can still achieve this by fining the relevant document and update their details, but I feel like there is a better solution.

Comment: As written before. Yes that is an option and should be a lot faster than using parent documents. It will come at a high cost at indexing time though.

Comment: @AndreasNeumann The links you provided is for version 2.x. How to achive the same with version 6.4?

Comment: f.e. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html