# Can I implement relationship with two indexes in elasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes (classes and students).

here each class has many students.
in this scenario, can I implement relationship between these indexes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119014/elasticsearch-simulate-foreign-key-behavior

Answer (score 0):

With Elasticsearch, the classic data model to implement your requirement is to put all students in class index.